# Is it possible to inject html code from one template to another in Qute?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-qute

In twirl you can pass html code from one template to another in this way:

```
@customFooter = {
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary block">Manage</a>
            </div>
        }

@particularPage(customFooter)
```

particularPage.scala.html

```
@(footer: Html)

@footer
```

Is there something like this in Qute with Renarde?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the twirl syntax but in Qute you can [include other templates](https://quarkus.io/guides/qute-reference#include_helper) and use template inheritance or pass some arguments to the included template. You can also use a more convenient [user-defined tags](https://quarkus.io/guides/qute-reference#user_tags).

This is how template inheritance looks like:

**footer.html**

```
<h2>Footer</h2> 
{#insert myFooter}This is default content, will be overwritten by the call site{/insert}
```

**page.html**

```
<p>Some page content...</p>
{#include footer} [1]
   {#myFooter} [2]
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary block">Manage</a>
        </div>
   {/myFooter}
{/include}

[1] Include the footer.html.
[2] Specify the content of the "myFooter" insert section.
```